# Is there a way to prevent XCode from downloading from the Internet?

Tags: xcode

I'm running XCode 3.2.2 on Mac OS X 10.6.6. My Activity Monitor shows that XCode periodically downloads from the Internet while running. Is there a way to prevent XCode from downloading from the Internet? My service provider imposes a limit on how much I can download before slowing my download to a crawl.

Comment: Belongs on Super User. And I hate your service provider.

Comment: @Radek This specifically relates to a software development tool, so is within the pervue of Stack Overflow I'd have thought. (See the "*software tools commonly used by programmers*" line in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).)

Comment: @middaparka whoops, but that wasn't in the faq when I joined SO 1 year and 7 months ago. :)

Answer (score 5):

Chances are this is just Xcode downloading updated documentation sets - to disable this, simply go to the "Documentation" option within Xcode preferences and un-check the "`Check for and install updates automatically`" option.

Answer (score 0):

System Preferences -> Security -> Firewall.

You should be able to add Xcode the list and make it not allow any connections.

Answer (score 0):

I went to XCode->Prefereces->Downloads->Documentation and clicked the minus button to move serval items to "Trash".  That deleted these huge documentation files that had added a few GB my Library/ directory.  Presumably it will now still do Xcode updates, but without the bloated documentation.